# What are some of the most frequently misused html tags?

Tags: html, tags, semantic-markup

What **non-deprecated** tags in html are commonly misused? How should they be used/what should they be replaced with? It would be awesome if we had some sort of guide to help people learning HTML.

An answer should include:

- The html tag in prominent text
- how it is commonly misused
- how we can avoid misusing it

Please only one tag per question. If you already see your tag in a post, please don't double post and instead edit your other mis-usage comments into that answer.

Answer (score 25):

```
<div> and <span>  <!-- no, really -->
```

I've seen a fair number of pages that use `<div>` and `<span>` tags with attached CSS classes or even inline CSS to the complete exclusion of more semantically charged tags like `<p>`, `<h2>` and `<em>`, even when the semantically charged tags would be more appropriate.  The only time the semantic tags are even thought of is when someone comes back and thinks about SEO.

Comment: Just beat me to it (mentioned it in a comment first). You make a clearer case for it. Upvoted.

Comment: @Graphain: I've been ninja'd plenty of times myself, it seems like par for the course on this site...

Comment: @Jeffrey, definitely. It would be cool if there was a merge answer function, so mine shows as something like a comment under yours etc.

Comment: What makes me cringe is when I see `<div align="center">`.  Heinous!

Comment: My favorite is `<div style="display:inline;">`.

Answer (score 23):

### `<a>`

The anchor tag should only be used to link to another location, NOT to trigger javascript. If I try to open a link in a new window and get some random javascript in my url bar instead, I'm not going to be happy. Inline javascript in the href attribute is even worse.

```
<a href='javascript:document.getElementById("foo").style.display="block"'>this is bad!</a>
```

Instead, use buttons as 'hooks' for javascript.

---

Also, avoid non-helpful text inside anchor tags. "Click Here!" and "Go to the page" are almost always poor choices. Use something like "[visit Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)" if the link needs to stand on its own. Otherwise, weave it into the content itself. [The Stackexchange Blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/?blb=1) has great examples of this, as does this post. Using better link text can help SEO, accessibility with screen readers, general usability, AND maintainability.

[See more on proper use of the anchor tag](http://www.grooveinteractive.com/resources/blog/anchor-tag-unleashed-part-1)

Comment: In old days, click/mouseover event only apply on links if you use NETSCAPE 4.6

Comment: I've read a research which stated that people click links with words "click here" about 15% more often. But then again 37% of all statistics on the internet are made up on the spot.

Comment: I maintain a codebase that spews out HTML that still does a lot of this. I'm currently of the school that no Javascript should be inlined, ever. No inline onclicks, no nothing. Give the element a unique ID or a semi-unique class to match on, and attach the Javascript on page load using JQuery. Much easier to refactor Javascripts, too.

Comment: What defines "proper use"? The HTML5 spec gives [an example](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a-examples) that isn't too far different from your one above. Neither '[button](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/button.html)' nor '[a](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html)' say anything about not being used to trigger JavaScript behaviour, so I'm not sure what the basis for this position is.

Answer (score 22):

```
<table>
```

People constantly use it for page layout rather than displaying data.

Comment: Still? I know this is the easy target and you'll score plenty of upvotes because of past table hell, but it's pretty rare to see a modern site using tables for layout anymore. In fact if it were not for long lost hours fixing nested table layouts I'd almost argue that tables are underused now when they should be (e.g. tabular data marked up with spans and divs). This is beside the argument that CSS fails pretty hard at a lot of desired page layouts (it's fine for styling, not so much for laying out).

Comment: @Graphain - I'll agree that many of the new popular web apps out there use the proper elements for layout...but look at the source of some of the pages of major corporations. Many of them still use tables for page layout.

Comment: I was just about to list this one.  Should've figured it'd be the first one hehe.

Comment: To be fair before css this was the only reliable way to position elements to the right and left of each other. Also it was commonly ised to position elements in SGML and other text markups.

Comment: It goes the other way too. Plus just recently tables were the only way to guarantee your layout would look the same across all mobile browsers, many of which didn't support css properly.

Comment: @MattMitchell ... well, y'know, the website you're on actually (stack overflow, I hear it's some kind of reference [pun intended]) uses tables for layout still, 7 years later. just inspect this very answer :)

Answer (score 15):

```
<label>
```

Not specifying the `for` attribute if the radio/checkbox is not within the tags.

Comment: True that, especially on radio buttons.

Comment: Personally, I'd call `<label>` *under*used rather than *mis*used.  Too many "professional" sites out there where you can't click on the checkbox/radio text! ;-)

Answer (score 10):

### `<b>`

### `<i>`

It's not egregious, but use of `<b>` and `<i>` instead of `<strong>` and `<em>`, respectively.

There are edge cases where `<b>` and `<i>` are preferable, but in nearly all cases, `<strong>` and `<em>` should be used, as they convey the meaning (strong or emphasized) rather than the particular styling that is associated with how they are to be displayed.

HTML tags are supposed to signify the structure and semantic meaning of a document, not provide a means for styling it. The method by which `<em>` gets styled is up to the stylesheet. It could be defined as `em { font-weight: strong; font-variant: normal;}`, and that's ok, since the design can dictate that that is how emphasized text should be styled. To use a `<i>` tag suggests that the text is italicized, and becomes semantically meaningless if you apply the same rules as above (where `<i>this is bold not italics<i>`).

Comment: actually, <i> is now commonly used for... icons! in major css styling guides examples, such as [font awesome](http://fontawesome.io/examples/). To be fair however, they do include a warning "we like the <i> tag for brevity, but using a <span> is more semantically correct".

Answer (score 7):

```
<font>
```

There are much more efficient ways of modifying text (ideally CSS).

Edit:  I guess  IS deprecated but I'll still leave it up for the sole reason that this tag should be killed entirely :D

And to hopefully compensate for my mistake I present my new answer:

```
<small>/<big>
```

Comment: I thought it was deprecated...?

Comment: `<font>` was deprecated in HTML 4, so doesn't meet the OPs criteria.

Comment: Upvoted as I agree. But only because it decentralises font maintenance (I have to check every page on the site). I'd take `<font>` over `<span style="font:">` though (not `<span class="legaltext">` though). You'd also have a genuine case for the `<font>` tag on a Font showcase site for instance.

Comment: It may be deprecated but the damn thing is still everywhere.  +1 from me.

Comment: Edited answer as to hopefully clear up some confusion.  I know OP said that it should only be 1 tag per poster but seeing as <font> is possibly ruled out I figured I'd go with another font-related tag.

Answer (score 6):

Ohhh, here we go!

```
<center></center>
<h7></h7> <!-- People think these things go on forever ;) -->
```

Just Google it: http://www.maximumpc.com/article/features/the_7_most_misused_html_tags_and_how_fix_them

Comment: `<center>` has been deprecated since HTML 4.

Comment: Meh, I missed the *non-depreciated* part. Oh well, people still use it even though it has been long dead...

Comment: I know!  Maybe the "non-deprecated" bit should have been in `<blink>` tags!

Comment: Not those again... I still encounter `<blink><h1>LOOK AT ME!</h1></blink>` in some websites... It makes me cry ;(

Comment: @Blender Assuming Firefox: `about:config` -> `browser.blink_allowed` -> `false`

Comment: Meh, Chrome > Firefox. I could have a huge argument about that, but I don't want to ;) I'm guessing Chrome disables it automatically, as I don't recall seeing blinking text on a webpage after switching to Chrome...

Comment: @Blender Better yet, I think Chrome complies to HTML4/5, not previous versions. In fact, sometimes on SO, images with `<img ... alt="My text" />` correctly (IIRC, this is correct behaviour) don't render the alt text as title text, as in most browsers.

Answer (score 4):

`<meta>` Plenty of site still try to put keywords into meta tags.  As far as I can tell, having meta keywords actually hurts your Google ranking because not only does Google ignore your meta keywords, it hurts your code to content ratio.  While seldom used, they are evel more seldom useful.  meta description is one exception - Search engines will sometimes reference it for a quick description.

Comment: yes, agreed although I still use meta keywords because there are 1% users who don't search with google, yahoo or bing

Comment: Google uses meta description as default description of any website.

Answer (score 4):

`<img>` doesn't rank that high, but think of every time you saw an image of content, with no alt text...

And again when it's used for layout instead of actually displaying an image to aid the text. 
Most of the people don't seem aware that if you want to display  an image that has no functionality, you should put it in your CSS.

Comment: Consolidated the two answers into one.

Answer (score 3):

```
<h*>
```

Multiple, and ridiculous, uses of `<h1>` on any given page. Maybe the `HTML` spec should shed some light on this topic.

Is there even a need for `<h6>` on a website? (Maybe if you were writing a report with multiple nested headings?)

Comment: Disagree. Heading tags are fundamental to the structure of a marked up document, and convey meaning to screenreaders and crawlers. <h2>Page Title</h2> is more semantic than `<div class="title>Page Title</div>`

Comment: What exactly do you disagree with? I never said we didn't need them, (apart from `<h6>` and that was more of a question) my point is that they're constantly misused.

Comment: Guess I should have read more closely. You're right, multiple uses of `<h1>` on a page is improper, from a semantic perspective.

Comment: multiple ridiculous use of h1... You beat me to it and I cudn't have said better... Great answer!

Comment: you can have as many h1 tags on your page as you like if you're using html5 - just need to put them in the right places

Comment: I don't essentially have any *serious* issues with multiple `<h1>` tags, if they're being used appropriately. It's more so, if the multiple uses serve no semantic purpose.

Answer (score 1):

`<imagemap>`

The `<imagemap>` is basically a linking tag where different parts of the image can be clicked to go to different links. It might look appealing but considering a first time user who goes to the website, he / she might not know where to click and which part of the image will take the person where. If the user’s internet bandwidth is less and the picture could not be loaded, it makes things all the more worse.

Hence this tag should be used only at places where the image is self-explanatory, maps for example.

Comment: An `<area>` can have a `title`, outline, mouse in/out behavior, tab focus and the mouse link cursor - it isn't different than any other link. I wouldn't say it is commonly misused , I'd argue most people don't even know it...

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit old data, but I guess it could be mostly accurate for today: http://code.google.com/webstats/2005-12/elements.html

According to this the most used presentational elements are **br** and **table** with its children.

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe>
```

Not Good:

```
<iframe src ="my_whole_site.html" width="100%" height="1500"></iframe>
```

Better:

```
<iframe src ="a_subsection_of_my_site.html" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>
```

Comment: This makes me think of [Dynadot Stealth Forwarding](http://www.dynadot.com/help/question.html?aid=10), which is essentially the first ("Now Good") option, marketed like some advanced feature of their hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Bare <li> tags are misused a lot because every browser will give you a workable list, without properly wrapping them in the ordered / unordered list tags, or finishing them properly.

heck, it works here.

see!